# How to transform a 2nd level category column with values to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to transform a "category" index from a `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` into multiple columns each holding the values of the row they belonged to before.
My index columns are `Index` and `Country`.

```
 Index      Country   Count
     0      'Canada'     10
             'Italy'     20
     1   'Indonesia'      5
            'Canada'      2
     2       'Italy'     14
```

To:

```
   Canada  Indonesia  Italy
0      10          0     20
1       2          5      0
2       0          0     14
```

It is quite close to the `get_dummies` function but I need to keep the count values to their correct positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one column `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` select column with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df['Count'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Country  'Canada'  'Indonesia'  'Italy'
Index                                  
0              10            0       20
1               2            5        0
2               0            0       14
```

If `MultiIndex Series`:

```
df1 = s.unstack(fill_value=0)
```